# Need help for creating msi file using wix with nant command line

Tags: wix, nant

I have one wix project file abv.wixproj and its product.wxs. I am able to generate its msi file by building it from Visual studio.

I would like to generate msi file using command (i.e. from .bat file).

I would like to generate msi file using nant. I got some code having `<target>` tag but not sure, in which file should I add this tag. should I create new file or in wsx file.

Kindly help me to share some example of nant commands to generate msi file using command line without Visual studio build

I have tried using `"%WIX%bin\candle" *.wxs -o obj\` but it is giving below error

> error CNDL0150 : Undefined preprocessor variable

I need one or more commands that will read wxs file and create msi or exe file by executing wix project

Answer (score 0):

The .wixproj is an MSBuild project file.  Just use the [msbuild task](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/msbuild.html) from NAnt and let the targets files handle all the candle and light details for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the details Christopher. Can you please share example of this file and command to execute this from command line instead of directly building from visual studio?

Comment: <msbuild project="${Solution.Filename}">
            <property name="Configuration" value="Release"/>
            <property name="OutputDir" value="${Output.Dir}"/>
        </msbuild>